# Упрощенные сокеты на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, сокет, сокеты

В общем, у меня есть написанная техподдержка на yii2, но я хочу обновлять её через сокеты, т.е. если человеку отвечают, там появляется надпись "техподдержка отвечает", как только техподдержка ответила, я хочу у клиента обновить страницу т.к. она через pjax работает, но все расширения, которые я смог найти работают по другому, в общем, кто знает как можно сделать такой функционал или хоть подскажите в какую сторону рыть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). Установка библиотеки не займет много усилий, просто в корне сайта создайте папку ratchet, а в ней файл Chat.php. Из [документации](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) скопируйте код и вставьте его в файл. Затем в папке [commands](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/tutorial-console/) создайте файл консольного приложения, который выглядит примерно так:

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use app\ratchet\Chat;
use yii\console\Controller;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function actionRun()
    {
        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new Chat()
                )
            ),
            8080
        );

        $server->run();
    }
}
```

После пишите код и запускайте сервер через консольное приложение Yii2. С начала советую попробовать сделать чат из документации, когда все заработает, начните реализовывать свою задачу.

Comment: ладно буду пробывать